# Hard disk not detected by Windows 8

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, windows-explorer

Windows 8 is not detecting my secondary hard drive I have installed in my system.

I have an older model Hitachi secondary hard drive of 300GB that worked fine when I had Windows 7 installed, but with Windows 8 it's not showing up in the Windows Explorer. The partitions of my other hard drive (same drive as Windows 8 is installed on) do show up, and the Hitachi does show up in Device Manager.

Could anyone help me out here as to how I can make it detect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got  it working by opening Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management, and assigning a drive letter to the hard drive.

No idea why the OS didn't do this itself.

Comment: You really wouldn't want the OS to mount filesystems you didn't ask it to. Mounting filesystems has consequences. For example, say one partition contains archival data and should only be mounted read only. (Otherwise, Explorer would find it, check to see how full it was, and change the access timestamps.) How would the system know to do that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thats nonsense, Windows auto mounts volumes all the time. In fact every time you plug in a USB it mounts a volume.

Comment: What part of it is nonsense exactly? I agree that Windows frequently does things you wouldn't want it to do. (And one of the worst things about it is it causes people to think it's being sensible and then when things do behave sensibly, they're mystified.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It doesn't make sense at all, it has always mounted the hard drive in earlier Windows versions. This is just a bug in the OS.

Comment: @TutorialPoint: I'm not sure it's a bug, it's inconsistent behavior. But the real problem is picking a dangerous default that people then begin to rely on. Then when you have to behave sanely, people are surprised.